# Merge two data frame using list to single value mapping using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
 A      [1,2]
 B      [3,4]
 C      [1,4,5]

another dataframe,
df1
col3    col4
 1       X
 2       Y
 3       Z
 4       W
```

Now I want to merge/join these two data frames using col2 of df and col3 of df1, so the the dataframe should look like,

```
col1   col2      col4
 A     [1,2]     [X,Y]
 B     [3,4]     [Z,W]
 C     [1,4,5]   [X,W]
```

Looking for some pandas shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with mapping by dictionary only if matching values:

```
d = df1.set_index('col3')['col4'].to_dict()
df['col4'] = df['col2'].map(lambda x: [d[y] for y in x if y in d])
print (df)
  col1       col2    col4
0    A     [1, 2]  [X, Y]
1    B     [3, 4]  [Z, W]
2    C  [1, 4, 5]  [X, W]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will show the approach first:

```
result = (
    df1.explode("col2")
    .merge(df2, left_on="col2", right_on="col3", how="left")
    .groupby("col1", as_index=False)
    .agg({
        "col2": lambda col: [item for item in col[col.notnull()]],
        "col4": lambda col: [item for item in col[col.notnull()]]
    })
)
```

Then, let's split it to steps for your understanding.

First, create your data which I suggest you provide yourself in your next question.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A", "B", "C"], "col2": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 4, 5]]})
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col3": [1, 2, 3, 4], "col4": ["X", "Y", "Z", "W"]})
print(df2)
```

Second, explode the first df.

```
result = df1.explode("col2")
print(result)

  col1 col2
0    A    1
0    A    2
1    B    3
1    B    4
2    C    1
2    C    4
2    C    5
```

Third, merge to left df.

```
result = result.merge(df2, left_on="col2", right_on="col3", how="left")
print(result)

  col1 col2  col3 col4
0    A    1   1.0    X
1    A    2   2.0    Y
2    B    3   3.0    Z
3    B    4   4.0    W
4    C    1   1.0    X
5    C    4   4.0    W
6    C    5   NaN  NaN
```

Finally, group by "col1"

```
result = result.groupby("col1", as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "col2": lambda col: [item for item in col[col.notnull()]],
        "col4": lambda col: [item for item in col[col.notnull()]],
    }
)
print(result)

  col1       col2    col4
0    A     [1, 2]  [X, Y]
1    B     [3, 4]  [Z, W]
2    C  [1, 4, 5]  [X, W]
```